# PDO :Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am trying to fetch page content  on  query basis like this

this is my home.php  code for getting pages

```
<?php foreach ($pages as $page) :?> 
<ul>
    <li><a href='<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>page.php?page=<?php echo $page['slug'] ?>'><?php echo $page['label'];?></a></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

in my **page.php** i've  this code

```
if(empty($_GET['page'])){
        $page=FALSE;    }
    else{
        $slug= $_GET["page"];
        $page= $db->prepare("SELECT  * FROM pages WHERE slug=:slug");
        $page= $page->execute(['slug'=>$slug]);

        $page= $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        var_dump($page);
    }
```

this is my table for pages [image]

now i am getting this error when  i go to page.php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Please help me to get it solved

Comment: why downvote when i put effort show my code/ db  ?  am i supposed to ask question here or you guys expect experts to put  everything perfect here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name variables **properly**.

`stmt->execute()` returns `bool`.

So after

```
$page = $page->execute(['slug'=>$slug]);
```

`$page` is `bool` and has **no** methods.

Comment: so i should use $page->execute(['slug'=>$slug]);  and then  $page= $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   fine ?